# How to Add element in a list with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just started using jQuery and I wanted to add *li* element in my HTML when I click on a button. Then I want to add a button that clear my list when it's clicked. This part works fine but when I click on clear button it disabled the other buttons.

My html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="res/MPS.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="res/MPS.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <title>Historique</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="filtres">
      <input id="filtre1" type="button" value="filter 1" onclick="addFiltre1()">
      <input id="filtre2" type="button" value="filter 2" onclick="addFiltre2()">
      <input id="filtre3" type="button" value="filter 3" onclick="addFiltre3()">
      <input id="filtre4" type="button" value="filter 4" onclick="addFiltre4()">
      <input id="filtre5" type="button" value="filter 5" onclick="addFiltre5()">

      <input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear filters" onclick="removeFilters()">
    </div>

    <div id="liste">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS :

```
function addFiltre1() {
    $("<ul>");
    $("<li>Filter 1</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function addFiltre2() {
    $("<ul>");
    $("<li>Filter 2</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function addFiltre3() {
    $("<ul>");
    $("<li>Filter 3</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function addFiltre4() {
    $("<ul>");
    $("<li>Filter 4</li>").appendTo("ul");
}


function addFiltre5() {
    $("<ul>");
    $("<li>Filter 5</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function removeFiltres() {
    $("#liste").html('');
}
```

I don't understand where is the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems, first you have a type error, you are using `removeFiltres()` and `removeFilters()`.

Second add `ul` to `$("#liste").html('');` to it looks like `$("#liste ul").html('');` then it works.

You can make your code a bit more clean using:

```
$('[id^=filtre]').click(function(){
  $("<li>Filter"+$(this).data('id')+"</li>").appendTo("ul");
});
```

**Demo**

```js
function addFiltre1() {
  $("<ul>");
  $("<li>Filter 1</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function addFiltre2() {
  $("<ul>");
  $("<li>Filter 2</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function addFiltre3() {
  $("<ul>");
  $("<li>Filter 3</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function addFiltre4() {
  $("<ul>");
  $("<li>Filter 4</li>").appendTo("ul");
}


function addFiltre5() {
  $("<ul>");
  $("<li>Filter 5</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function removeFiltres() {
  $("#liste ul").html('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtres">
  <input id="filtre1" type="button" value="filter 1" onclick="addFiltre1()">
  <input id="filtre2" type="button" value="filter 2" onclick="addFiltre2()">
  <input id="filtre3" type="button" value="filter 3" onclick="addFiltre3()">
  <input id="filtre4" type="button" value="filter 4" onclick="addFiltre4()">
  <input id="filtre5" type="button" value="filter 5" onclick="addFiltre5()">

  <input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear filters" onclick="removeFiltres()">
</div>

<div id="liste">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: For the type error, it just a copy/paste error. I change ```$(#liste").html('');``` in ```$(#liste ul").html('');``` and now it works fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MissKnacki No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 4):

you have to clear **#liste ul**  not **#liste**. when you are making empty your **#liste** it's removing your appendTo target **`<ul></ul>`** tag. After that action Again you are trying to *appendTo* in **`<ul></ul>`** Tag but its already removed. so you have to clean inner **#liste ul**

your declaration **removeFilters()** and you **button function** name will be same Because your button is calling that function that is declared with same name.

you can use direct **empty()** method for clear inner HTML at your div instance of html('') method.

```js
function addFiltre1() {
    $("<ul>");
    $("<li>Filter 1</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function addFiltre2() {
    $("<ul>");
    $("<li>Filter 2</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function addFiltre3() {
    $("<ul>");
    $("<li>Filter 3</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function addFiltre4() {
    $("<ul>");
    $("<li>Filter 4</li>").appendTo("ul");
}


function addFiltre5() {
    $("<ul>");
    $("<li>Filter 5</li>").appendTo("ul");
}

function removeFiltres() {
    $("#liste ul").empty('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtres">
      <input id="filtre1" type="button" value="filter 1" onclick="addFiltre1()">
      <input id="filtre2" type="button" value="filter 2" onclick="addFiltre2()">
      <input id="filtre3" type="button" value="filter 3" onclick="addFiltre3()">
      <input id="filtre4" type="button" value="filter 4" onclick="addFiltre4()">
      <input id="filtre5" type="button" value="filter 5" onclick="addFiltre5()">

      <input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear filters" onclick="removeFiltres()">
    </div>

    <div id="liste">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
```